# Puppeteer, the request in Fetch.requestPaused is faster than targetcreated in the browser

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

Hope doing well.
I have created the puppeteer app to intercept the all request/response.
The some request aren't intercepted on `page.on("request")` method and I had to put the code - `await targetClient.send("Network.setBypassServiceWorker", { bypass: true, });` to intercept the service worker requests as well.

So I have put the interception code on the browser fetch api.

```
await browserClient.send("Fetch.enable", {
      handleAuthRequests: true,
      patterns: [
        {
          requestStage: "Request",
        },
        {
          requestStage: "Response",
        },
      ],
    });

    browserClient.on(
      "Fetch.requestPaused",
      async (fetchEvent: Protocol.Fetch.RequestPausedEvent) => {
        const {
          requestId,
          request,
          resourceType,
          responseStatusCode,
          responseErrorReason,
          responseStatusText,
          frameId,
        } = fetchEvent;
console.log(frameId);
});
browser.on("targetcreated", (target: Target) => {
 const targetId = (target as any)._targetId;

console.log(targetId); // actually targetId is same like requestId
});
```

In the console message, `console.log(targetId)` is printed after than `console.log(frameId)`.
What there is the frame id does mean that the frame has been created.
So `console.log(targetId)` should be first printed but `console.log(frameId)` is the first.
could you please explain why?

You can please test the url as "https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo".